# How to rename a list of variables

Tags: variables, rename, stata

I generated a number of dummy variables from a variable indicating the the relevant quarter, labelled quarter, with the following command:

```
tabulate quarter, generate(timeq)
```

This generates a set of dummy variables that range from `timeq1` to `timeq68`.

I am trying to think about a way to rename these variables to change the names in the following way

`timeq1` into `1995q1`
`timeq2` into `1995q2`
`timeq3` into `1995q3`
`timeq4` into `1995q4`
...
`timeq68` into `2011q4`

Comment: You should create a minimum, complete, verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people know what you're looking for and what you've tried already.

Comment: Thank you Elliott, I will proceed asap, Many thanks.

Comment: Cross-posted at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1376031-how-to-rename-a-set-of-variables-indicating-quarterly-time-dummies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out, this question sorely lacks a good MCVE. but an answer is possible.

Note first that the ambition to create variable with names beginning with `1` and `2` is futile as it is a basic rule that such names are not legal. However, a beginning underscore is allowed.

The problem of renaming requires, I think, at least one loop. In fact, it seems easier to back up and create the variables from scratch.

The first part of the code just creates a sandbox for play.

```
clear
set obs 68
gen quarter = yq(1994, 4) + _n
format quarter %tq
```

The second part is *ad hoc* code for the problem. Note that variable labels can take the form desired.

```
forval y = 1995/2011 {
    forval q = 1/4 { 
        gen _`y'q`q' = quarter == yq(`y', `q')   
        label var _`y'q`q' "`y'q`q'" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Prof. Cox, I do thank you very much for your kind reply. The code does exactly what I as looking for. I will next time post also here the link of my question posted on statalist. Many thanks for your kindness.

Comment: Fine: note that accepting the answer would give you (and me!) some reputation.